# cannot use python intersection set with ROS point lists

Tags: python, set, intersection, ros

i try to find a intersection set of two position lists, in ROS

so i write a code in python, and i have two lists, such as :

```
position1 = Point()

position1.x =1

position2 = Point()

position2.x=2

a = [copy.deepcopy(position1),copy.deepcopy(position2)]

b = [copy.deepcopy(position1)]
```

then, when i try to get intersection of those two list a and b

it return me an answer: set([])

that's ridiculous,

normally i should have an answer like: set(a).intersection(set(b)) = set([position1])

if anyone could help me to fix this problem?

it's great thankful for viewing this problem

and i appreciate for your watching and answering.

thanks in advance.

here is my testing code

```
import rospy,copy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
class test():
 def __init__(self):
  position1 = Point()
  position1.x =1
  position2 = Point()
  position2.x=2
  a = [copy.deepcopy(position1),copy.deepcopy(position2)]
  b = [copy.deepcopy(position1)]
  print  set(a).intersection(set(b))
  print 'a', set(a),'\n'
  print 'b', set(b)

if __name__=='__main__':
 try:
  rospy.loginfo ("initialization system")
  test()
  rospy.loginfo ("process done and quit")
 except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
  rospy.loginfo("robot twist node terminated.")
```

BTW,ROS Point type is posted here: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html

Comment: It don't see how it can returns `set([])`, show all the code.

Comment: thanks for answering , i write a testing code and attach it in the end of my question

Comment: `set`s rely on `hash` and `==` to work... is `hash(position1)` the same as `hash(position2)` and does `position1 == position2` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: @Ninja Puppy a[0]==b[0] is true, because they are both position1, but hash(a[0]) and hash(b[0]) is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't returns `set([])` but prints `set()` (nitpicking maybe but it's not the same thing).

Actually it's the expected behavior :

- a set keeps only unique elements
- unique is defined by having the same hash
- the default hash comes from **hash**() method
- **hash**() uses the id of the object
- you deepcopy your objects so they have different ids
- so they're different

I don't know why you think you need deepcopy but if you put your points directly in lists, it will works as expected

Answer (score 0):

@Ninja Puppy delete an answer, which i think it helpful as well, so i add it here. while, if this is forbidden or Ninja Puppy feel sick of this, i will delete this answer too. following is his answer

> Okay, going by your comment:
>
> ```
> a[0]==b[0] is true, because they are both position1, but hash(a[0]) and hash(b[0]) is different
> ```
>
> One way is to create a new Point that supports a hash that's
>   meaningful for use in a set, eg:
>
> ```
> class NewPoint(Point):
>     def __hash__(self):
>         return hash(self.x) # maybe self.y as well?
> ```
>
> Ideally your hash should include the same attributes that
>   `Point.__eq__` uses.
>
> Then use NewPoint to construct your objects instead.